# R convert data table to vector in reverse order

Tags: r, data.table

what is the fastest way to convert the data.table:

1: A B C

2: D E F

3: G H I

into the vector: G H I D E F A B C

I use:

X <- X[order(nrow(X):1),]

X <- melt(t(X))$value

But my feeling is, that this can be optimized :-)

Thank you

Comment: What do you recommend me exactly? I'm using stackoverflow not often

Answer (score 2):

One option is to reverse the index, transpose to a matrix and concatenate

```
c(t(X[.N:1]))
```